# GSON fails parsing JSON with string space

Tags: java, json, gson

I have the following object:

```
public class ParameterWrapper<T> {

    private String type;

    private T value;

    public ParameterWrapper(String type, T value) {
        this.type = type;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

I am serializing it into JSON using the Gson library. When `value` contains a string with no spaces, it works perfectly. When `value` contains a string with spaces, I see the following exception:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 28

For the following JSON:

```
{"Plaintext":{"type":"String","value":"hello there"},"Key":{"type":"Number","value":"1"},"SINGLE_FUNCTION":{"value":"1-0"}}
```

However with the following:

```
{"Plaintext":{"type":"String","value":"hellothere"},"Key":{"type":"Number","value":"1"},"SINGLE_FUNCTION":{"value":"1-0"}}
```

The JSON is parsed successfully. Is this a known issue? I've ran the JSON through a validator and it is perfectly fine.

Edit:

The vagueness of the question wasn't unnoticed. I was hoping this was an existing issue. The application is huge, which is why prying out a small, compilable example is difficult, but I'll do what I can!

OKAY. So firstly, the below JSON is send to my controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/update-state")
public
@ResponseBody
String updateState(@RequestParam(value = "algorithmId") String algorithmId,
                   @RequestParam(value = "state") String state) throws InvalidParameterException {

    Algorithm algorithm = algorithmService.getAlgorithmById(Integer.parseInt(algorithmId));
    algorithm.execute(executorService.parseAlgorithmState(state));

    return gsonBuilder.toJson(algorithm.getState().getParameterMap());
}
```

On the call to `parseAlgorithmState(state)`, it moves down to this method:

```
@Override
public AlgorithmState parseAlgorithmState(String json) throws InvalidParameterException {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Map keyValueMap = (Map) gson.fromJson(json.trim(), Object.class);
    ...
```

The line `Map keyValueMap = (Map) gson.fromJson(json.trim(), Object.class);` is where the exception is initially occurring.

Comment: Could you show how you serialize/deserialize the data? This issue seems weird. I've created a small program based on your problematic input and it works fine. You can check it there: https://gist.github.com/alexcrt/d898d5780cf5da4b0bbd Posting the code that reproduces the error would help...

Comment: I've added the route through the code. Thanks for your attention @AlexisC.

Comment: It's hard to reproduce. Try to print what comes from your `updateState` function but based again on your input the `keyValueMap` contains  `{Plaintext={type=String, value=hello there}, Key={type=Number, value=1}, SINGLE_FUNCTION={value=1-0}}` at the end (I've just done `Map keyValueMap = (Map) new Gson().fromJson(gson.toJson(o), Object.class);`). To be honest I don't think it's an issue with Gson (otherwise it would have been a very embarassing bug), but with the way you manipulate your data, or with strange non-printable characters (who knows?).

Comment: I thought that but I've called trim on the strings, as well as printing out the raw bytes. I've not seen any weirdness so far. I will keep investigating.

Comment: Its weird. And the json string you get is the same as you posted in the question? There's certainly a place where there's an inconsistency with the string you are trying to parse :/ Maybe try to write a custom deserializer. Otherwise I have no more clues to help :-(

Comment: I pulled the Json string directly out of chrome Dev tools myself. And I compared it with the out put of logs on the back end. All valid! Some dark.. Dark magic is going on here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74476/discussion-between-alexis-c-and-christopher).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had this same issue.  The problem is that the character is a non-breaking space, char(160).  If you paste this in the body of a request using POSTMAN, you'll visually be able to see the characters (They look like gray dots).  Gson doesn't like them.

Answer (score 2):

So after some discussion, the following workaround worked:

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
JsonReader jr = new JsonReader(new StringReader(s.trim())); 
jr.setLenient(true); 
Map keyValueMap = (Map) gson.fromJson(jr, Object.class);
```

`setLenient(true)` makes the parser a bit less restrictive.

Looking at the documentation every restrictions that `setLenient(true)` disable are not present in your Json string, except the [first one](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html#nonexecuteprefix) (which may be the issue since you're getting the string from a webserver).

Comment: I have an arrayList and want to have space (next line : /n)  in stings

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
  Gson gson = new Gson(); 
  Map keyValueMap = (Map) gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(s.trim()), Object.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with this JSON:

`{“id”:“”,“title”:“Hello SiteCore”,“description”:“This is the body text from SiteCore”,“type”:“Information”,“displayType”:“Banner”}`

The parser was pointing to the char coming right after the first white space.

`com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 26 path $.null`

After much search and having some extra pairs of eyes, we found that the JSON (coming from a Sitecore database) has been created with `“` instead of `"`.

Changing all `“` chars to `"` solved my problem using the usual Gson code:

```
    @JvmStatic
    fun convertFromJsonString(data: String): Message? {
        if (data.isEmpty())
            return null
        return Gson().fromJson(data, Message::class.java)
    }
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.