# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 app crash

Tags: android, json

i got this error but i think my json are right

this is my json

```
 {
"data": [
{
"id_movie": "7",
"id_review": "4",
"rating": "4",
"review": "menginspirasi",
"created_at": "2019-01-11 18:50:11",
"id_user": "1",
"title": "Bohemian Rhapsody",
"release_date": "2018-12-03",
"cover": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/lcwmDAYt22k/maxresdefault.jpg",
"trailer": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lcwmDAYt22k",
"id": "3",
"genre": "Science Fiction",
"poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOTM3NzE5OTE1Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzQwNjM3NjM@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg"
}
]
}
```

and i got this error and it referring to this code

```
fun getReviewList(genre: String?) {
    view.showLoading()

    GlobalScope.launch(context.main) {
        val data = gson.fromJson(apiRepository
                .doRequest(localhost.getReview(genre)).await(),
                ReviewResponse::class.java)
        println(data)

        view.showReviewList(data.data)
        view.hideLoading()
    }
}
```

this is my ReviewResponse class

```
data class ReviewResponse(
    val data: MutableList<Review>)
```

this is my Review class

```
data class Review(
    @SerializedName("id_review")
    var reviewId: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("id_movie")
    var movieId: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("poster")
    var poster: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("rating")
    var rating: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("review")
    var review: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("created_at")
    var date: String? = null
```

)

please help what is wrong with it

Comment: Could you add the code for `ReviewResponse` pls and all the models it depends on?

Comment: yes i added it @Fred

Comment: It might be an extra char that looks like a space, which appears in fron of the response. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29438159/gson-fails-parsing-json-with-string-space

Comment: Indeed the models seem correct. Could you debug and make sure that's the actual json you're receiving? The error says it was expecting the `ReviewResponse` object, but got a string. Sometimes this happens with some servers when they quote the entire json response or send a completely different format - i.e., just a simple string.

Comment: it don't want debug because when i open the app it crash @Fred

Comment: am i have to give lenght in my data in database? @mcassiano

Comment: @QubaisyAndiyantama you can always start it in debug with the right break point or even add the line `Debug.waitForDebugger()`. This shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @QubaisyAndiyantama nope, but if there is an invisible character in front of the response, Gson isn't expecting it, hence "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING". Maybe try trimming the response before you actually pass it to Gson. open this URL in Chrome and go to "View source" to see if there are any chars you don't expect.

Comment: when i debug it before the data it don't have anything because it before the data called. when i debug it after the data it crash @Fred

Comment: i think there is no invisible character on it. i've seen it @mcassiano

Comment: call .trim() on the response or substring it removing the first char, just out of curiosity. everything looks alright with your setup