# trying to Map my Json String data to an object. I'm using Gson to parse the data. Data get parsed but when i give Space in Value it gives me Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, gson

EXCEPTION - **com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 26 path $.[0].STATE"**

This is My POST REQUEST.
Where Data is an Object, id & resource is String

```
private String id;
private String resourceName;
private Object data;
```

```
{
    "id": "150",
    "resourceName": "Fabrik-Resource",
    "data": {
        "RECORD": [
            {
                "STATE": "TORONTO CITY"
            },
            {
                "WORK": "SERVICE"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

`Now if i give Space between TORONTO CITY` ,It will give me an exception

`com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 26 path $.[0].STATE"`

but when I send requests without spaces as keys and values like -

```
        "RECORD": [
            {
                "STATE": "TORONTOCITY"
            },
            {
                "WORK": "SERVICE"
            }
        ]
    }
```

It work **but not with Space**

CODE -

```
    public ResponseEntity<MasterBlockChainResponse> dummy(@RequestBody(required=false) Masterpayload valueobject) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        MasterBlockChainResponse response = new MasterBlockChainResponse();
        Object json = valueobject.getData();
        
        Map<String, Object> map = gson.fromJson(json.toString(), Map.class);
        response.setId(valueobject.getId());
        response.setResourceName(valueobject.getResourceName());
        response.setData(map);
        
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(response);
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is because of the line:

```
Map<String, Object> map = gson.fromJson(json.toString(), Map.class);
```

when you use toString method it doesn't convert the object into a legit JSON Object, try and use ObjectMapper. i.e.

```
Map<String, Object> map = gson.fromJson(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(json), Map.class);
```

Quick Comparison of the difference :

- ToString Produces:

> {RECORD=[{STATE=TORONTO CITY}, {WORK=SERVICE}]}

- writeValueAsString Produces:

> {"RECORD":[{"STATE":"TORONTO CITY"},{"WORK":"SERVICE"}]}

Code Snippet:

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Object json = valueobject.getData(); //{RECORD=[{STATE=TORONTO CITY}, {WORK=SERVICE}]}
    String jsonString = gson.toJson(json); //{"RECORD":[{"STATE":"TORONTO CITY"},{"WORK":"SERVICE"}]}
    Map<String, Object> map = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Map.class); //{RECORD=[{STATE=TORONTO CITY}, {WORK=SERVICE}]}
    ArrayList x = (ArrayList) map.get("RECORD");
    x.get(0); //{STATE=TORONTO CITY}
    x.get(1); //{WORK=SERVICE}
```

Comment: hi thanks, @Rickky13 for your answer I already did that using ObjectMapper. and it is not parsing data as I wanted. so that's why go with gson.

Comment: you could.. `Map<String, Object> map = gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(json), Map.class)`

The crux is that toString doesn't give you the Json format for Gson to handle properly.

Comment: I tried this.  when I convert the object into gson.toJson getting response as - {RECORD=[{STATE=MINNEOPOLISCITY}, {WORK=SERVICE}]}.
Which is not a valid Json. so in that case when i put a space between MINNEOPOLIS CITY... it gives the exception as above.

Comment: hmm, could you elaborate on how did you do it? `{RECORD=[{STATE=MINNEOPOLISCITY}, {WORK=SERVICE}]}` still seems like it is from a object.toString() result

Comment: above value is in  blockChainResult.getData()... then i did this
`Object json = blockChainResult.getData();
log.info("sss ----=== "+json); // ***#Output. "{RECORD=[{STATE=TORONTO CITY}, {WORK=SERVICE}]}"***

String m = gson.toJson(json);
Map<String, Object> map = gson.fromJson(m.replace("\"", ""), Map.class);`

Comment: you can fix it by removing the replace.. `Map<String, Object> map = gson.fromJson(m .̶r̶e̶p̶l̶a̶c̶e̶(̶"̶\̶"̶"̶,̶ ̶"̶"̶)̶, Map.class);` p/s yes you are logging out the string version

Comment: Actually, the data after parsing it to JSON is coming like this ---- 
"{RECORD=[{STATE=MINNEOPOLISCITY}, {WORK=SERVICE}]}"
so, that's why I used to replace to remove ".....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246329/discussion-between-rickky13-and-krishan).

Answer (score -1):

Your object data is a simple object because you need that data like this for parsing:

```
Data{
List<String> RECORD;
}
```

so your principal class:

```
Class{
    String id;
    String resourceName;
    Data data;
}
```

And not a map key-value. In this way you shouldn't have any problems

Comment: @pavaraz97 Thank you for the answer but there is a reason I used Object type as Data. Because In the Data object the data can be anything not only this RECORD data.. It can be any JSON data.
So according to me, this solution is not generic enough to answer the question.

Comment: i have seen this topic that maybe could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29438159/gson-fails-parsing-json-with-string-space

Comment: i saw this topic, that say you have to wrap the strings into double quote, https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1286
i dont' know if it works , but  i hope so